# Hold letters and numbers in std::string C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to create a simple program to take serial numbers as an input and then searche them to find out what year the product was made in.

I am having some trouble getting a std::string to hold both numbers and letters.

```
std::string serial;

serial = b1234;
```

For example, if I run this through my compiler, I get the error message 'invalid digit in decimal constant'.

Is there a simple way to hold letters and numbers together in a string?

Comment: `serial = "b1234";` (note the double-quote marks).

Comment: Did your dog eat your C++ book?

Answer (score 2):

Basic C++ syntax says that string literals are delimited by `"` quotation marks.

```
const std::string serial = "b1234";
```

Comment: The mentioned error message is interesting though. Is the compiler actually trying to interpret a binary literal (despite the missing leading `0`)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The compiler is actually trying to compile some other code that the OP didn't share with us; the true error message is "b1234 undeclared identifier" (and variants).

Answer (score 1):

No. A a std::string is a string of characters, so you can't save integers in that string.

You're trying to write "b1234", I guess. Have you read any [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) on C++ strings?